# IOS Development: Game application creating user accounts

Tags: mysql, sqlite, facebook-ios-sdk, ios

I am looking to create a game application and have done a lot of video tutorials and read a lot of books on IOS.

I would like to know more information on techniques and common practices for game applications. I do not want to setup a game using GK/Game Center. Ideally I would like the user to have the option to enter some basic fields like Username/Password or to login with Facebook to create a user account.

The game will be peer-to-peer and played by one user completing a move that sending to the other and vice versa.

I have had a look at the Facebook SDK and the Hackbook sample application and that part is all fine.

I would like to know if someone can provide more information, video tutorial, eBooks and/or sample code for applications that create user accounts. What methods do they use to create these for multi player games, how these are then managed in terms of multiple users being created and playing the game, how these are scalable etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have a server to store user accounts and game data. If you don't want to create the server yourself, I'd recommend using a backend-as-a-service platform. I've had good luck with Parse
https://www.parse.com/

They have some samples and SDK functionality for user accounts and Facebook integration. That should get you started. Your game data will be saved in an object that acts very similar to an NSDictionary that you can persist on their servers.

If you want a different provider, just search for "backend-as-a-service"

Comment: Thanks, I had also heard of Amazon S3 is this similar?

Comment: Amazon S3 does provide an iOS SDK. I haven't used it but I believe it is more low-level, so you'll have to implement more things yourself. It's not bad, just different.